# Is RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer also work on ipad detecting?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer also work on ipad detecting?

I don't see any  RuntimePlatform .ipadplayer

```
Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimePlatform.html

Check out the following link. It will be OSX Player.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is incorrect, `Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer` will return `true` on an iPad.